# debian8 not response after restart/stop/start

Tags: linux, debian

few months ago I got access to a VPS with installed Debian 8 Jessie. 
The strange thing for me was that after perform some action (like service  [stop|start|restart], debian not notify me (ex: Restarting nginx: nginx, like old debian 7 wheezy). 
Yesterday, i installed on my virtual machine Debian 8 Jessie, but the "bug" persists.
Should I install something extra library, or to set up them?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For verbose output see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73207052/1950345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian uses `systemd` now.

```
systemctl start example1
```

Investigate why `systemd` hangs on startup or on reboot/shutdown.

Increase verbosity via cmdline: Add "systemd.log_target=kmsg systemd.log_level=debug"

```
[ /etc/default/grub ]
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="systemd.log_target=kmsg systemd.log_level=debug" <--- Add here (by uncommenting you can easily switch to debug)

# update-grub
```

Comment: This is very confusing for me.
If I understood correctly, if the operation is successful, there is no need for communication.

Answer (score 0):

Systemd is not as verbose as the old SysV scripts, so your described "bug" is intended behaviour.

The old commands, like "service" are just simple symlinks / script which delegate the work to systemd.
As far as I know this is the same for the /etc/init.d scripts.